# Is it possible to load ld-linux.so.2 with DllImport in Mono?

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I need to dynamically load shared objects in Linux (and in the future, OS X, but one thing at a time) and it seems that actually trying to ld-linux.so.2 will always fail with DllNotFoundException. Trying to load it in a C program seems to fail as well (dlopen returns null).

Is there any other way to dynamically link libraries in Mono without DllImport, possibly a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong *'library'*. You should use libdl (which works both on Linux and OSX).

It would be better if you used DllImport, though, together with Reflection.Emit if dynamic support is needed.

Comment: Using libdl is a lot less hassle due to the nature of the library this is for.

Here's a link if you're interested
https://github.com/GeirGrusom/PlatformInvoker